# How to implement Invoke method?

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke

I've been searching a lot of topics but it's already too complicated to understand. I don't even see the this.Invoke(); method.

Here's my scenario:

I have this UserControl called test1.xaml and it has a frame control called frame1

Basically test1.xaml.cs contains

```
public test1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
           this.frame1.Content = new test();
    }
```

Next, I have another usercontrol called test2.xaml and I would like that has a button called button1. What I want to happen is that when test2.xaml is loaded and the user clicks the button, I would like to switch it's navigation page to the next page.

```
public test2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow MW = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        MW.label1.Content = MW.tabControl.SelectedIndex;
        TabItem page = MW.tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        test1 a = new test1();
        a.frame1.Navigate(new Uri(@"/UserControls/salesBtn.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

This is the code that I have in my test2.xaml.cs. Now I know I'm doing it wrong on button click event since I'm just instantiating a new user control and not referencing to the actual control that is no longer running. How do I invoke or how do I make test1.xaml's frame navigate to the said path?

Comment: In WPF, you need to use this.Dispatcher.Invoke()

Comment: Could you provide what arguments to I have to pass on my Invoke method?

Comment: Update 1: Hello, I tried this.Dispatcher.Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { a.frame1.Navigate(new Uri(@"/UserControls/salesBtn.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); }); ... but it did not work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Invoke. Invoke is for handling cross-thread calls. You seem to need some App level Frame manager.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { <your method goes here> }));

Comment: How could I put my method if I need to access it to another control? I did test1 accessTest = new test1(); it just shows the control but wont let me manipulate it

Comment: Henk: What's that lol. I only would just like to manipulate the control property from another class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > I only would just like to manipulate the control property from another class

Then expose it as a public method.

For example:

```
public class MyFirstObject {
  private string MyValue {get;set;}
  public void UpdateMyValue(string newValue) { MyValue = newValue; }
}

public class MySecondObject {
  MyFirstObject myFirstObject;
  public MySecondObject {
    myFirstObject = new MyFirstObject;
    myFirstObject.UpdateMyValue( "someNewValue" );
  }
}
```

Comment: For those following along at home (or on the non-static feeds) the ongoing chat log begins here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/71248#71248

Comment: Drach helped me without having to use Invoke method. Just have to reference the class properly. Thanks drach!

Comment: @lnluis anytime, I didn't mind at all once I figured out what you had going on